# Search Query using PHRETS not Working

Tags: php, rets

I am new to PHRETS. And need to build one search panel which could search and display using PHRets and Rets Server. Here its getting connected but doesn't show results. I want something that can show results nicely.

**SEARCH.PHP**

```html
<?php
$rets_login_url = "http://connectmls-rets.mredllc.com/rets/server/login";
$rets_username = "xxxxxxxx";
$rets_password = "xxxxxxxx";

require_once("phrets.php");

$rets = new phRETS;

//echo "+ Connecting to {$rets_login_url} as {$rets_username}<br>\n";
$connect = $rets->Connect($rets_login_url, $rets_username, $rets_password);

//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($rets);
//echo "</pre>";

if ($connect) {
    
        echo "<p class=\"success\">Connected</p>";
        

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$search = $rets->SearchQuery("Property","ResidentialProperty","(ListDate=1990-01-01+)",array("StandardNames" => 1));
while ($listing = $rets->FetchRow($search)) {
   echo "Address: {$listing['StreetNumber']} {$listing['StreetName']}, ";
   echo "{$listing['City']}, ";
   echo "{$listing['State']} {$listing['ZipCode']} listed for ";
   echo "\$".number_format($listing['ListPrice'])."\n";
}


$rets->FreeResult($search);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
else {
        echo "<p class=\"error\">Not connected:<p>";
        print_r($rets->Error());
        exit;
}

if (!empty($rets->err)) {
    echo "HTTP {$rets->err}\n";
}

$last_req = $rets->LastRequest();
if ($last_req['ReplyCode'] != 0) {
    echo "RETS {$last_req['ReplyCode']}: {$last_req['ReplyText']}\n";
}
//echo "Server reports: ".$rets->GetServerVersion()."\n";
?>
```

**NOT SHOWING RESULTS. PLEASE HELP AS SOON AS POSSIBLE.**

Comment: 1) Use RETSMD.com to make sure you're using the right Property, Class, and field names. 2) Try searching without the StandardNames option and instead using the SystemName for ListDate. 3) Also, some RETS servers require multiple fields to be used in the SearchQuery (i.e. Status, Property Type), so check to make sure you're not missing any of these.

Comment: Can you enable the debug_mode as true and check the error log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$search = $rets->SearchQuery("Property","ResidentialProperty",
          "(ModificationTimestamp=2011-01-01T00:00:00+) , 
           (ListPrice=300000)", array("Limit" => "20", 
          "Format" => "COMPACT","StandardNames" => "1","Count"=>1) );
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice.